# How can I use git grep as effectively as possible?

Tags: git, version-control, grep

I know that I can use `fgrep` to search fast without using regexes.
I can also use `grep` to search for regexes.
But it seems `git grep` is a lot faster than these options when I use it in a git repos.
What I need is some guidance on how to use it in order to be more productive.
Right not the only thing I do is `git grep string` in all the files.
It does what I want but how can I improve myself and exploit `git grep` better?

Comment: Have you even read the `git help grep` ?

Comment: @sputnick:I am not looking how to use it.I am interested in common "recipes"/tips that people find productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can make `git grep` faster in some cases: [it comes with a fixed strings flag](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-grep.html):

> ```
> -F
> --fixed-strings
> ```
>
> Use fixed strings for patterns (don’t interpret pattern as a regex).

So if you don't need to use a regex to look for multiple forms of a pattern (i.e. you just need an exact match), you could use this.